# Are HEMA (Historical European Martial Arts) questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

HEMA ([Historical European Martial Arts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_European_martial_arts)) is the study and recreation of how people fought and duelled with one another in Europe during the mediaeval and Renaissance period. It has been popularised in recent years by youtube channels such as [Scholagladiatoria](https://www.youtube.com/user/scholagladiatoria), [Lindybeige](https://www.youtube.com/user/lindybeige) and [Skallagrim](https://www.youtube.com/user/SkallagrimNilsson).

Are questions about HEMA strictly off-topic, or are they allowable on this SE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We do have a few examples of martial-arts questions floating around. I'd say that if the questions are concentrated around people or events, it would most likely be on-topic here (although if you want an answer, it helps greatly if it is *documented* people or events).

However, if its details about things like how forms were accomplished, you might have better luck on the [Martial Arts SE](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/).